# Login even after wrong creditionals flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i get navigate to the home page even i entered the wrong credentials. i get the error that 'no user fond' but how to stop it.

```
signIn() async {
    if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
        formkey.currentState.save();
        try {
            _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Home()));
        } catch (e) {
            print(e.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not awaiting for any response from auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword which is what you'd need to do in order to check and see if they're actually authenticated.

So:

```
await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

Comment: Great answer Adrian! That indeed explains it precisely. I can't believe I overlooked the lack of `await` when trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code:

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: "nope@stackhack.com", password: "secret");
  print("Signed in");
}
catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

I get the error printed, and not the `"Signed in"` message. The error contains a `code` property, which has a value `"ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND"`. So to respond to this specific error, I could do something like:

```
if (e.code == "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND") {
  print("User not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions, one is

```
signIn() async {
  if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
    formkey.currentState.save();
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      if (user != null && await user.getIdToken() != null) {
        final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
        if (currentUser.uid == user.uid) {
          print("Success in signing, you can now navigate");
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

other is (thanks to Frank)

```
signIn() async {
  if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
    formkey.currentState.save();
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: "nope@stackhack.com", password: "secret");
      print("Signed in, you may want to navigate now");
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    }
    catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND") {
        print("User not found");
      }
    }
  }
}
```